# how to replace N characters without having to press <esc>, is it possible?

Tags: key-bindings, substitute, replace, repeated-commands

In command mode, `r` replaces the character under the cursor by the one pressed right after typing `r` without going into insert mode, so there's no `esc` to press.

`5r` replaces the 5 characters starting from the one under the cursor by the **same** single character typed after `5r` (the new character is repeated 5 times).

I would like to replace N characters by N other characters (some or all of them different from each other) without having to press `Esc` *(or any other key)* after I typed the N characters, that is, I'd like to avoid using e.g. `5s`.

I couldn't find any way to do so. Is it possible? If there's no existing pre-defined command, what key binding could provide this functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To meet all your requirements a function will probably be needed in addition to a mapping. Put both of these in your Vim start-up file (e.g. `.vimrc`) and the functionality will be available each time you launch Vim.

```
func! ReplaceNChars(n)
    let inchars = ""
    let idx = a:n
    echom 'Enter ' . a:n . ' characters: '
    while idx > 0
        let inchars .= nr2char(getchar())
        let idx -= 1
    endwhile
    exec 'norm! R' . inchars
endfunc
```

This function takes a number and then waits for that many characters to be entered by the user. Then Normal mode `R` is used to replace whatever is currently under the cursor with the entered text.

The code is very straightforward so I won't go into the details.

Here's the mapping...

```
nnoremap <expr> <silent> <leader>R ':<C-U>call ReplaceNChars(' . v:count1 . ')<CR>'
```

To use it, in Normal mode enter the number of characters to replace, then, assuming you have the default leader key, enter `\R`. (Replace this part with whatever you want.) You'll be taken to the command line. Enter the appropriate number of characters and then the replacement will occur. No extra keys like <kbd>Esc</kbd> or <kbd>Enter</kbd> are required.

Unlike the code this mapping uses some constructs that may not be well known. Some details (with Vim help links):

- [`<expr>`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/map.txt.html#%3Amap-%3Cexpr%3E) : The right side of the mapping is an expression that is evaluated and the result is the actual mapping.
- [`<silent>`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/map.txt.html#%3Amap-%3Csilent%3E) : Prevents the mapped command from being echoed on the command line.
- [`<C-U>`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/cmdline.txt.html#c_CTRL-U) : Clears the command line before inserting the rest of our command.
- [`v:count1`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#v%3Acount) : Variable that contains the last user-entered count. If no count has been entered defaults to 1. In our case the default will mean that the mapping will behave much like the `r` command.

*I haven't done any negative testing or tried any corner case input. Just normal use cases.*

Comment: Tested and meets my needs all right (and probably those of many others since performing what I ask seems to have called for elsewhere as well). For anyone wondering where to put the function, it can go in `~/.vimrc` (and this `.vimrc` has to be sourced, ex from within a vi session in command mode, do `:source ~/.vimrc`).

Comment: Note: when the number of characters to be replaced goes beyond the end of the current line, line is expended with the additional character(s) (not a problem at all, it can even be desired).

Answer (score 1):

This is obviously hardcoded to 5. But it should be possible to generalize it to `n` if you need. It demonstrates the trick.

```
nmap <F1> :execute "normal c5l".nr2char(getchar()).nr2char(getchar()).nr2char(getchar()).nr2char(getchar()).nr2char(getchar())<CR>
```

Comment: Interesting trick, but when I test it "live" in a vi session, it hides the 1st line of my file (not really a problem) and when I'm done typing my 5 new characters it asks I press `ENTER`, so while it does indeed prevent from typing `esc` I still have to type another key which I'd like to avoid (I'll make my question more precise on this point). Also how could I make the mapping applicable to substituting `n` characters rather than `n` being hard-coded?

Comment: Weird, I don't experience those behaviors on my system. Anyway, it's moot since the general function has been posted.